# Prevent Spring Boot app start from failing when database does not connect

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a Spring Boot application that is connecting to a postgres instance. My application.properties looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=${POSTGRES_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${POSTGRES_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
```

I don't have any code that manually establishes a database connection, Spring does it all automatically. My problem is that when the app cannot connect to the database, the application fails to start at all. How do I make it so that a successful database connection is not a condition for the app to start?

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in you props file
**spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true**

Comment: This did not work for me, still getting `[PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution`

Comment: Which version of spring boot are you using?

Comment: 2.2.7.RELEASE is my version.

Comment: Can you add your properties file in your question? Definitely you have wrong configurations

Answer (score 0):

It seems `'spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true'` is deprecated.
The new property is '`spring.sql.init.continue-on-error`' and to continue even with DB error it should be set as true

Comment: Mind adding a source to your answer on the deprecation and/or the new property? Would make the answer more useful for others experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score -2):

You usually do that *outside your application* in your start-up script. Only fire it up, once your dependencies are running. I don't know if you're containerizing or something, but https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on should give you an idea.

That said, you certainly can implement code that does exactly that in your `public static void main(String... args)` method before firing up your `ApplicationContext`, e. g. checking if PostGres is up already by trying to connect through plain JDBC.